# Mock method from class 'b' that is called in class 'a'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test a method in the class test.controller.ts, this method also happens to call a method from a different class that is being tested seperately, so I want to mock that call.

Here is an example setup to show what i'm trying to do.

TestController.test.ts

```
import {TestController} from "../../src/controllers/test.controller";
import {TestService} from "../../src/services/test.service";

describe("Test TestController", () => {

    test("exampleController", () => {

        jest.mock('../../src/services/test.service');
        let testService = new TestService();
        let testController = new TestController();

        // Mock testService.exampleService so it returns 2.

        let result = testController.exampleController();
        expect(result).resolves.toBe(2);
    });

});
```

test.controller.ts

```
import {TestService} from "../services/test.service";

export class TestController {
    private testService: TestService;

    constructor() {
        this.testService = new TestService();
    }

    public async exampleController() {
        return await this.testService.exampleService();
    }
}
```

test.service.ts

```
export class TestService {
    public async exampleService() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

How do I mock the method 'exampleService' so that the call to the method 'exampleController' from test.controller.ts uses this mocked version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the `testService` field of your `TestController` class.
But with your current code, that isn't possible as it's a private member.
This is why using dependency injection is preferred, so we need to change your constructor to this,

```
  constructor(testService: TestService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }
```

Instead of instantiating testService within the constructor, we are now passing an object of `TestService` so that it is easy to mock.

And then you can test it like this,

```
import {TestController} from "./controller";
import {TestService} from "./service";

jest.mock('./service.ts')

describe("Test TestController", () => {

    test("exampleController", async () => {
       
        let testService = new TestService();
        jest.spyOn(testService, 'exampleService').mockResolvedValue(2)

        let testController = new TestController(testService);

        let result = await testController.exampleController();
       
        expect(result).toBe(2);
    });

});
```

Here you create an object of `TestService`.
Then you create a spy on the `exampleService` method of the `testService` object and mock its resolved value to return 2.
Then you pass it to TestController's constructor, this is called dependency injection, which makes it easier to test.
And then you proceed to assert as per your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

For mocking functions you can use the [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.1/stubs/) library. It can be done as shown below:

```
let testService = new TestService();
      sinon.stub(testService, "exampleService").callsFake(function fakeFn() {
                return 2;
     });
```

Comment: I know Jest does have mocking build in so i was really hoping to just use the build in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify the return values and full-on replace the implementation of a function with a mock function, it can be done with `jest.fn` and `mockImplementationOnce` method on mock functions.

`TestController.test.ts` should look like

```
import {TestController} from "../../src/controllers/test.controller";
import {TestService} from "../../src/services/test.service";

describe("Test TestController", () => {
    test("exampleController", () => {
        jest.mock('../../src/services/test.service');
        let testService = new TestService();
        let testController = new TestController();

        // Mock testService.exampleService so it returns 2.
        testService.exampleService = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(2));

        let result = testController.exampleController();
        expect(result).resolves.toBe(2);
    });

});
```